# Open source spring MVC aplication with Junit tests?

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4, mockito, hamcrest

Soon we will be starting a new project. It will be Spring MVC based web application. For the first time we have decided to start writing tests in the application.

We will be using Junit, Mockito and Hamcrest for writing tests.

Since this will be our first time to write tests and we also do not have anyone in the team with prior experience in writing tests, we are looking for some sample apps which we can use as a reference.

We have gone through net and red few articles on how to write tests using junit etc. what are the best practices while writing tests etc but haven't seen any real world application so far.

We do not want to start writing bad tests.

Please help.

Comment: You won't be writing perfect tests from day one, no matter how hard you try.  This will be a learning curve for your team.  One suggestion would be that you could use http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get feedback on some of your tests when you start writing them.  The only danger is that the SE community contains at least as many opinions as it does users.

Answer (score 4):

This is by far not the ultimate list but some recommendations from my experience

1. Really try to test units, especially since you are using JUnit (as opposed to testNG for example). What this means is that if you find some run order in your tests being required then you are not testing units, now you are testing integration or functionalities
2. Related to #1, I strongly recommend using a mocking library, which it seems you do. Me, I use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), it is very simple to use and the tests end up very readable. The reason why you need this is that any reasonable class has dependencies on other classes (if not btw, your classes are probably not very cohesive) or external resources (DBs, etc) and because in unit testing you are supposed to test only one class at a time, you need to mock out the other classes that are not under test.
3. Design for testability. This one is tricky, because I believe you should not expose (i.e. make *public*) methods just for testing sakes, but sometimes you might need to make some private methods package-protected so that the unit tests can call them directly. This is very useful when your methods execute things that you don't want to execute in a testing environment (like creating files) so you can separate those especific parts into separate methods that you can then avoid in your test. Make sure you comment in the javadoc when a method is not supposed to be used outside of unit tests
4. Try to avoid creating/opening resources in your working methods. For example, instead of using a *File* parameter that then you open in your method and create an InputStream, pass the InputStream directly. This way when you test you can pass a memory stream. Or in a more general way, [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) goes very well with unit testing. Every time you call `new` in your methods, it will probably make your unit tests more difficult to run and/or assert
5. If you notice that to run your test for a method you need to first call lots of outside methods to configure the state of your unit under test then you are better off doing some refactoring. This is a good indication of high-coupling. This is one of my favourite things about unit testing, the fact that you create a second user for your class helps you double check your design.

For sure a lot of people won't agree with some or all of these, to those people, don't keep it to yourself, comment on this answer so that there's another POV close by. It will help me too

Answer (score 0):

I also recomment this book, it has many good practices and smells that will help you to find bad practices in your unit tests.

http://www.walmart.com/ip/4013717?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=3&adid=22222222227002169628&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=14146085830&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=35052138190&veh=sem